# TSQL in sql server 2008 --writing stored procedure to merge records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Am wondering how to write a stored procedure to aggregate the rows in the data.

Sample data:

```
Start End id
1     2   01
2     3   01
3     0   01
3     4   02
4     7   02
```

In this I should merge the rows with the same id of the sequential rows and start attribute of beginning row is less than end value of the last row. Also should store them in a table

Output of sample input:

```
Start End id
1      3  01
3      0  01
3      7  02
```

The logic is failing with the procedure I wrote.

Comment: Show us the procedure you wrote.

Comment: ..and explain how it is failing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is good (no gaps in start/end):

```
select  MIN(Start) [Start], 
        MAX(End) [End],
        id
    from YourTable
    group by id
```